# "TypeError: XXXX is not a function" after assigning a value to a class object

Tags: typescript

Let's say, we have a class in Typescript:

```
class Greeter {
  greeting: string;
  constructor(message: string) {
    this.greeting = message;
  }
  greet() {
    return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
  }
}
```

Now if you do:

```
let greeter = new Greeter('World');
greeter.greet();
```

everything works fine.

However, if you do:

```
let greeter = {greeting: 'World'};
greeter.greet();
```

it throws an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: greet is not a function
```

Now, I know what causes this error. It is a plain object which gets assigned to the class object and has no idea what greet() is.
The error does not go away even if I typecast the object.

```
let greeter = {greeting: 'World'} as Greeter;
```

I worked around this by putting a static function in my class, like so:

```
public static fromObject(greeter: Greeter) {
  return new Greeter(greeter.greeting);
}
```

So, I have two questions here:

1. Is this a bug?
2. Is there a better way to approach this?

*(The reason I have a plain object to start with is that I receive it from a web service.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The error does not go away even if I typecast the object.

[Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (they're not casting) don't have any effect whatsoever on the object. All that adding a type assertion there does is make TypeScript think the object is a `Greeter` when it isn't.

> 1. Is this a bug?

Not in TypeScript or JavaScript, no.

> 2. Is there a better way to approach this?

Your `fromGreeter` is a reasonable way to approach it (though the type annotation should be `object`, not `Greeter`), if you have a non-`Greeter` object with a `greeting` property (and possibly others) that you want to create a `Greeter` from. Or you might overload the constructor so it accepts a plain object and copies the properties.

If you want to trust that the plain object will only have valid properties that should be on the greeter, you can use `Object.assign` to copy them to the new instance:

```
public static fromObject(greeter: object): Greeter {
  return Object.assign(new Greeter(), greeter);
}
```

I'd be remiss if I didn't say that it's *possible* (as of ES2015) to change the prototype of an object, but it's not recommended and has performance impacts. So it would be *possible* to actually convert your existing plain object into something using `Greeter.prototype`:

```
// Not recommended, but possible
Object.setPrototypeOf(plainObject, Greeter.prototype);
```

It's almost always better to create a new instance and copy the properties to it instead, as your `fromObject` does.

Comment: Well, it is not about why I would want to write it that way. I receive the value using a webservice and would like to use the class functions to get something out of that value.
A lot of things in Typescript go against what we generally know about OOP.

Comment: @funkycoder - *"I receive the value using a webservice and would like to use the class functions to get something out of that value."* That makes sense (and would have been a good thing to put in the question :-) ). So yeah, either have that static method, or have the constructor accept an object (perhaps conditionally). I've updated the answer a bit.